# Как распарсить JavaScript Object (не валидный JSON) в Golang?

Tags: javascript, json, golang, объекты, json-encode

Вначале валидный JSON:

```
v1 := `{
        "middle" : {
        "src": "pictures/product/middle/14906_middle.jpg",
        "place" : "#preview-img",
        "title": "343880-090-slantsy-nike-benassi-just-do-it"
        }
    }`
```

Теперь валидный JavaScript Object, но не валидный JSON:

```
v2 := `{
        middle : {
        src: 'pictures/product/middle/14906_middle.jpg',
        place : '#preview-img',
        title: '343880-090-slantsy-nike-benassi-just-do-it'
        }
    }`
```

Подскажите как распарсить второй вариант? Обычный encoding.json.Unmarshal() ругается на невалидность.

```
error: invalid character 'm' looking for beginning of object key string
```

Может быть есть какая-то библиотека в которой этот нюанс можно настроить?

Update:

Можно запустить VM https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto и передав ей немного дополненный текст получить из неё нужное поле.

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/robertkrimen/otto"
)

func BenchmarkVMGet(b *testing.B) {
    vm := otto.New()

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        st := `
            {
                middle : {
                    src: 'pictures/product/middle/14906_middle.jpg',
                    place : '#preview-img',
                    title: '343880-090-slantsy-nike-benassi-just-do-it'
                }
            }
        `

        vm.Run(`
            obj = `+st+`
            src = obj.middle.src;
        `)
        src, err := vm.Get("src")    // <-----
        _ = src
        _ = err
    }
}

# go test -bench=".*" ottotest
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkVMGet     30000         58103 ns/op
ok      ottotest    2.367s
```

Однако есть минусы:

- может прилететь произвольный кусок текста и выполнять его бездумно не правильно (вспомним **eval** в **php**)
- достаточно медленно
- используется очень большая библиотека - плохая зависимость

Плюсы:

- всё таки достаточно быстро
- можно не останавливать VM, а пушить туда через Run, но если пушить бесконечно остаётся вопрос - умрёт однажды или не умрёт - без хорошего знания внутренностей библиотеки сказать этого заранее нельзя

Я всё ещё ищу другие варианты, чисто под задачу распарсить **object** и не выполнять лишних операций.

Comment: Может поискать парсер json5 на go? Вот, например, https://godoc.org/github.com/rolldever/go-json5

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/rolldever/go-json5 это обёртка над github.com/robertkrimen/otto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть библиотека для этого [launchpad.net/rjson](https://godoc.org/launchpad.net/rjson). Если ключ соответствует регулярному выражению

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*
```

Обращаю внимание, что в JavaScript символ `$` может быть использован - а здесь нет.

Однако [launchpad.net/rjson](https://godoc.org/launchpad.net/rjson) не поддерживает одинарные кавычки в значениях. Что бы это поправить был сделан форк который можно взять вот тут: [github.com/mantyr/rjson](https://github.com/mantyr/rjson)